# Scrape images from scanned pages with python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to get images out of scanned pages, but I am getting entire document as result. The pages are in scanned form and saved in pdf. I want images only but all pages are extracted instead of extracting only images from pages. I have tried this code. Any help would be great

```
import fitz
from PIL import Image
import io

# open the file
pdf_file = fitz.open("directory")

# iterate over PDF pages
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):

   # get the page itself
   page = pdf_file[page_index]
   image_list = page.get_images()

   # printing number of images found in this page
   if image_list:
    
    print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")
   else:
     print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)
   for image_index, image in enumerate(page.get_images(), start=0):
      xref = image[0]
      base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
      image_bytes = base_image["image"]
      image_ext = base_image["ext"]
      image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
      image.save("ouput lib")
```

The above code is converting pdf to png of the scanned pages where as I need images present in each page.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I think you're just missing a ".jpg" or ".png" of your final
line (or some other type of file extension)

```
image.save("ouput lib")
```

change to

```
image.save("ouput lib.png")
```

At least, that was how I fixed it for myself (with the bare minimum amount of changes)

But, keep in mind. You're not saving each individual picture with this setup. You're just rewriting the same file over and over again (if there are multiple pictures)

If you want a separate file for each picture, try a string format:

```
image.save("ouput lib_{}_{}.png".format(page_index, image_index))
```

(In its entirety)

```
import fitz
from PIL import Image
import io

# open the file
pdf_file = fitz.open("../path/to/file.pdf")

# iterate over PDF pages
for page_index in range(len(pdf_file)):

    # get the page itself
    page = pdf_file[page_index]
    image_list = page.get_images()

    # printing number of images found in this page
    if image_list:

        print(f"[+] Found a total of {len(image_list)} images in page {page_index}")

    else:
        print("[!] No images found on page", page_index)

    for image_index, image in enumerate(page.get_images(), start=0):
        xref = image[0]
        base_image = pdf_file.extract_image(xref)
        image_bytes = base_image["image"]
        image_ext = base_image["ext"]
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_bytes))
        image.save("ouput lib_{}_{}.png".format(page_index, image_index))
```

Comment: Hi, this is causing the same thing. I want images only out of scanned pdfs, but entire page is extracted.